# Laravel resolving dependencies for a closure

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel

Laravel is able to automatically inject dependencies in controller constructs, etc.
For example:

```
class Test {
    public function __construct(Request $request) {}
}

App::make('Test');
```

The controller's constructor will receive the appropriate request facade.

Is there a way to do this with closures?

For example:

```
$closure = function(Request $input) {};
App::make($closure); // resolving the closure dependencies
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible, you may read through the IoC container code here:

`laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php` on line `466`

As you see it tries to resolve and parse parents Class's `__constructor` method through reflections.

I think that would be interesting to implement, as it's quite possible by extending the `Container` class to also support closures.

I have made a couple of tests to make sure it is possible, so here they are:

```
    class t4 {
        public $x = "inject me";
    }

    interface t5 {}

    $t3 = function(t4 $test) {
        return print($test);
    };
    $r = new ReflectionFunction($t3);
    $params = $r->getParameters();
    $injection = $params[0]->getClass();
    if (!$injection->isInstantiable()) {
        throw new Exception('Provided type hint is not instantiable');
    }
    $typehinted = $injection->newInstance();
    print($typehinted->x); // prints "inject me"
```

Type hinting t5 will throw the exception.

This answers the question

> Is there a way to do this with closures?

As to how implement it, in my opinion you should have perfect knowledge of how reflections and Laravel IoC container work. I think this will not be implemented in near future as Laravel is basically built on classes. What are your use cases?

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I was hoping it would be possible somehow. I'm going to implement it myself, just the way you showed it. My use case: I like closures, and they have a good use in PHP, in certain scenarios. Using an automated dependency injection would be nice here.

Comment: Great you liked it, may you please provide use cases in Laravel? I'm just interested :)