# How to inject class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I have two of these classes

```
namespace Kharota\Libraries;

class Input {

    public function input($input)
    {
        echo "inèut";
    }

}
```

and Form Class

```
namespace Kharota\Libraries;

class Forms 
{
    public static function form($params, $callback)
    {
        if(is_callable( $callback)) {
            call_user_func( $callback);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call like this

```
use Kharota\Libraries\Forms;
use Kharota\Libraries\Input;

...

Forms::form( [], function(Input $input) {
    $input->input( [] );
});
```

But I am getting error

> (1/1) ErrorException
>   Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::{closure}() must be an instance of Kharota\Libraries\Input, none given

How I can fix it?

Comment: inside your `form` function, you called `$callback` but you didn't pass any parameter to it, which it needed `$input` which is of type `Input`

Comment: Shouldn't `use Kharota\Libraries\Form;` be `use KharotaStudio\Libraries\Forms;` ?

Comment: Sorry i fixed it but error is still the same. It has something with Input $input because error is related to that

Comment: @Wreigh thanks for comments how I can pass parameter to callable I want Input class to be injected into callable so that I can use input functions in callable function.

Comment: if you really want to do an automatic closure injection, you can look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779805/laravel-resolving-dependencies-for-a-closure

Comment: @linktoahref its typo but its not the reason. I think type hint is not allowed by laravel as referred by Wreigh

Answer (score -1):

You should write `use Kharota\Lib...` between `<?php`  and `class OtherClass`.

Comment: I think this belongs to the comment section.